# Animate an already loaded geojson line using d3

Tags: javascript, animation, d3.js, leaflet, geojson

I am trying to animate a few geoJSON lines. I want to use this d3 animation:
http://bl.ocks.org/zross/2f2baa1699b8ae38c768

However I have already loaded my geoJSONs via a database and wonder how this part can be adapted for a variable rather than a file?

```
d3.json("linestring2.json", function(collection) {
        var transform = d3.geo.transform({
            point: projectPoint
        });
```

I appreciate any help, Cheers :)